# Determine differences between date stamps and reference dates

Tags: r, date, if-statement

I’m working with a dataset of 191K observations that has individual records with date stamps throughout the period of 2014-2020.

I have four reference dates (19 Sept 2014, 9 Sept 2016, 26 Oct 2017, 19 June 2019) that I need to determine the difference between each record’s date stamp.  The rub is that I only need positive values for `difftime`:

- if the difference is <180 then the difference will be used;
- if the difference between dates is 180-365 days, then the value will be set to 180;
- if the difference >365 days, then NA;
- no negative values will be included.

Sample data:

```
Date            Difftime     Notes:
11 Nov 2014     53           19 Sept 2014 used as reference
10 Jun 2015     180          19 Sept 2014 reference, but >180
5 Jan 2018      71           26 Oct 2017 reference
1 May 2019      NA           No reference date within 365 days
```

In summary, a record’s date stamp needs to be compared to a relevant reference date (i.e., the closet, post-record date).  I think I can do this in a number of individual `ifelse` statements after creating separate variables for each of the reference dates, but I don’t want to clutter my dataset with more variables (even if I can remove them post-assessment).  I’d appreciate any insights into how to code for this assessment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible approach.

I created a vector with the four reference dates (in order):

```
ref_dates <- as.Date(c("2014-09-19", "2016-09-09", "2017-10-26", "2019-6-19"))
```

and a data.frame with sample data:

```
sample_data <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2014-11-11", "2015-6-10", "2018-1-5", "2019-5-1")))
```

You can use `findInterval` to identify the closest reference date for each sample date, without going over ("price-is-right" approach):

**Edit**: I created a function to return the closest date (or `NA` if it precedes all of the reference dates):

```
my_fun <- function(x) {
  the_date <- ref_dates[findInterval(x, ref_dates)]
  return(ifelse(length(the_date) == 0, NA, the_date))
}
```

The function would be called as follows, including `origin` as date becomes numeric:

```
sample_data$Ref_Date <- as.Date(sapply(sample_data$Date, my_fun), origin = '1970-01-01')
```

That would give you this:

```
        Date   Ref_Date
1 2014-11-11 2014-09-19
2 2015-06-10 2014-09-19
3 2018-01-05 2017-10-26
4 2019-05-01 2017-10-26
```

You can calculate difference between the two dates (in this case stored as integer):

```
sample_data$Difftime <- as.integer(round(difftime(sample_data$Date, sample_data$Ref_Date, units = "days")))
```

Then, you can apply your rules. Options could include `case_when` (from `dplyr`) or newer `fcase` from latest `data.table` (it is fast).

```
library(data.table)

setDT(sample_data)

sample_data[ , Difftime_final := fcase(
  Difftime < 180L, Difftime,
  Difftime < 365L, 180L,
  Difftime >= 365L, NA_integer_
)]
```

Which gives the final result:

```
         Date   Ref_Date Difftime Difftime_final
1: 2014-11-11 2014-09-19       53             53
2: 2015-06-10 2014-09-19      264            180
3: 2018-01-05 2017-10-26       71             71
4: 2019-05-01 2017-10-26      552             NA
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for the code!  I have one question, at this point: can you clarify the coding for the [findInterval()] statement?  It appears that the answer posted was truncated to '[findInt'.  Thanks for your help; much appreciated!

Comment: Ben, no worries!  I honestly didn't know what the gray bars beneath the text meant!  Let me have a go and I'll get back to you.  Sorry for the bother!!!

Comment: Ben, There seems to be a problem when 'RefDate' is set to be a character or Date (my edit):  Error in as.POSIXct.default(time2) : 
  do not know how to convert 'time2' to class “POSIXct”.  When I changed the format from 'as.character' to 'as. Date', the structure is "Date[1:1], format "2017-10-26".  So, why would there be a POSIX error?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Here's what I tried: Records2$RefDate<-sapply(Records2$Date, function(x) as.Date(ref_dates[findInterval(x, ref_dates)])).  In your original answer, the code said 'as.character', not 'as.Date', as what I tried.  I then ran: Records2$Since2<- as.integer(round(difftime(Records2$Date, Records2$RefDate, units=c("days")))) and which produced the error code: Error in as.POSIXct.default(time2) : 
  do not know how to convert 'time2' to class “POSIXct”.

Comment: Ben, Here's the entire code that I used:
ref_dates<- as.Date(c("2014-09-19", "2016-09-09", "2017-10-26", "2019-06-19"))
Records2$RefDate<-sapply(Records2$Date, function(x) as.Date(ref_dates[findInterval(x, ref_dates)]))
Records2$Since2<- as.integer(round(difftime(Records2$Date, Records2$RefDate, units=c("days"))))

Comment: Ben, tried your suggestion, but no joy; here's the error message:

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, RefDate, value = c(17465, 17465, 17053,  : 
  replacement has 179698 rows, data has 191934

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219067/discussion-between-doug-robinson-and-ben).